# How to check the status of a website using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on some urls. I want to check the status of a website using selenium. I tried to check the status via **urllib** it says status is ok but sometime when I enter that url to selenium or check it in browser it's not working. so is there any method I can check the status of a website with selenium so that I can know it will work. my code is below.

```
import time
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from http import HTTPStatus
from selenium import webdriver
from Base_Class import *


# get the status of a website
def get_website_status(url):
    # handle connection errors
    try:
        # open a connection to the server with a timeout
        with urlopen(url, timeout=3) as connection:
            # get the response code, e.g. 200
            code = connection.getcode()
            return code
    except HTTPError as e:
        return e.code
    except URLError as e:
        return e.reason
    except:
        return e


# interpret an HTTP response code into a status
def get_status(code):
    if code == HTTPStatus.OK:
        return 'OK'
    return 'ERROR'


# check status of a list of websites
def check_status_urls():
    http = 0
    https = 0
    db_conn = base_class.table_selected_urls()
    db_conn.execute("SELECT url FROM SELECTED_URLS LIMIT 50")
    urls = db_conn.fetchall()
    url_protocols = ['http://','https://']

    #driver = base_class.web_driver()
    #driver.current_url()
    for url in urls:
        for url_protocol in url_protocols:
           full_https_url = url_protocol + url[0]
           Http_Https_status = get_website_status(full_https_url)
        # interpret the status
           status = get_status(Http_Https_status)
    # report status
           #print(f'{status:5s}')

           if full_https_url.split(':')[0] == 'https' and status == 'OK':
               print('https:: '+ full_https_url + ' ' + status)
               https += 1

           if full_https_url.split(':')[0] == 'http' and status == 'OK':
               print('http:: ' + full_https_url + ' ' + status)
               http += 1

    print('Number of https :: ' + str(https))
    print('Number of http :: ' + str(http))


# list of urls to check

# check all urls
check_status_urls()
```

Comment: Is this just for a daily status report?  Remember that, just because a site was responding 10 seconds ago does not mean it is responding now.  If you're using this as a check before you fetch the web site, then skip this and just handle the error when you scrape it.

Comment: @TimRoberts can you please gave me an example

Comment: @TimRoberts I need to store record of urls that how many will work in selenium and in that one how much is http or https. so I can draw a  cumulative distribution function (CDF) plot.

Comment: (1) You can assess http vs https without fetching the page.  (2) Any page you can fetch will work in Selenium.  You are asking the question "Does this web page respond?"  You don't need Javascript for that, so there's no point in bring in Selenium.  Just use `requests`.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is a really heavy package, so steer away from using it unless you really have to use it. In this case, you don't need to use Selenium at all to check the status. All you need to do is use the `requests` library. Like this:

```
import requests


# check the status of a list of websites
def check_status_urls(urls):
    https = 0
    http = 0

    for url in urls:
        r = requests.get(url)
        if r.url.startswith('https'):
            https += 1
        elif r.url.startswith('http'):
            http += 1

    print('Number of https: ' + str(https))
    print('Number of http: ' + str(http))


# check all urls
check_status_urls(['https://google.com', 'https://stackoverflow.com',
                   'https://httpforever.com'])
```

Output:

```
Number of https:: 2
Number of http:: 1
```

Comment: I have to use selenium. because I need this urls in my further tasks. so this why I will know that url is working with selenium.

Comment: @stackoverflow You can still use the URL with selenium later on. Using `requests` for a part of your program won't stop you from using Selenium later, so this answer would work.